# Molecular Dynamics Software for Coarse Grained Polymers

Tags: resource-recommendations, software, molecular-dynamics, polymers

I am looking around for MD software that I can use to simulating polymers and I can't decide which software I should use.

I would like to simulate the swelling of crosslinked polymers, and I would like to do a coarse grained simulation. The most popular MD software I have found are GROMACS and LAMMPS. Are either of these suitable for course grained simulations? I tried GROMACS briefly and it was complicated. I'm reluctant to spend a lot of time learning it if there is better software available.

Another suite of programs I found is OCTA. It is a bundle of polymer simulation engines for working at different scales. It has an engine for coarse graine simulations but it doesn't seem as flexible and the (English) community seems very small. Does anyone have any experience with OCTA?

Comment: I am currently using LAMMPS for my research on polymer nanocomposites. It is relatively easy to use, just spend some time taking a look at the examples you can find online and read carefully the related documentation.

Comment: ^ What @valerio92 said. LAMMPS has many models in it that will work. Dissipative particle dynamics (DPD) is included in it, and is probably what I would recommend for coarse grained simulations. I've only used it briefly, so I can't provide a detailed answer on it unfortunately.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a software request and not physics.

Comment: Here is a question from 2011 that is also looking for MD software. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10311/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because altough it is about physics, software recommendation questions are allowed only on the softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @peterh This question does not contain enough objective criteria to be on-topic at softwarerecs.SE, cf. [this meta post of that site](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336). Please do not suggest migrations of questions without being certain about their on-topicness at the target.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [software recommendations are off-topic here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3981/50583).

Comment: @peterh, I browsed the softwarerecs.stackexchange site and it is overwhelmingly for general computer utilities. I don't think my question will get useful answers there.

Comment: I take issue with the comments that this question is off topic. In the tour page for Physics.stackexchange, it says I can ask about "Experimental technology used in physics or astronomy". For computational / theoretical physics the software is part of the technology used.

Comment: @user668074 There is a long history of conversations on allowing/disallowing software recommendations: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2898/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3980/ https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9304/

Comment: @tpg2114, I looked at them and I never saw a clear consensus. Some people think  the questions should go to SU or SO, but others argue that if they are too specific for physics, they shoud be allowed here. That is my position on my question. It is specific for physics, I don't expect users on SU or SO to have the expertise to answer my question.

Comment: @user668074 Which is fair -- I don't think there is a clear consensus. But you need to bring it up on [Meta](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com) because we can't discuss it here through the comments.

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on [Comparison of software for molecular mechanics modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_software_for_molecular_mechanics_modeling) which looks quite useful (with other similar lists under 'See also').

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, thanks for the link, it's a good overview. I am hoping for some more depth with my question.

Comment: Related meta post: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9912/2451

Comment: Consider posting at [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @sammygerbil, I will think about it, I generally know the software I want to use, but I want specific information their use for a specific application. For this I want insight from the Physics community.

Comment: Just curious: isn't it "coarse grained", rather than "course grained"?

Comment: @akhmeteli, Yes, my mistake

Answer (score -2):

I've been working with LAMMPS, NAMD and ESPResSoMD and I can tell you ESPResSoMD is the best package for simulating coarse-grained models. It has two versions: Tcl and python based interface ( the python one has not been released officially, but you can get a development version of it).

Comment: Please mention other details, including pros and cons, learning curve, cost, compatibility, and prerequisites. You may want to mention alternatives as well: resource recommendations with only one entity are usually not appreciated.