# Software for simulating gas of hard particles (i.e. polyhedra?)

Tags: resource-recommendations, simulations, software, molecular-dynamics

I was wondering if there existed a kind of software I could use to simulate a gas of polyhedra, such as tetrahedra. They would interact through entropic interactions only, i.e. excluded volume.

I'm not an expert in simulation so any kind of suggestion is welcome. This is just for recreational purposes.

Comment: The molecular dynamics code LAMMPS is highly modular and supports aspherical finite-sized particles, see [here](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_howto.html#howto-14). I don't believe they have polyhedra already implemented though but it probably wouldn't be hard to implement if you look at their existing finite-sized-particle packages.

Comment: I'm assuming you're really asking to simulate a **non-ideal** gas?  From what I remember, an ideal gas assumes the extent of the gas particles is negligible, and that orientation is unimportant

Comment: @CortAmmon thanks, corrected. I had in mind "not interacting via a potential."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a request for software and not about physics.

Comment: @KyleKanos It's about software to simulate physics. It's not so clear that questions like this one should be considered off-topic (see for example https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9912/allowance-of-computational-physics-questions).

Comment: @valerio so what if it's software to simulate physics, it's still a software request, which isn't on topic (e.g., [this meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5603/25301))

Comment: @KyleKanos There is no consensus on this in the community. Please read the meta post I linked, which is a lot more recent than the one you linked. The reception of questions like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336562/molecular-dynamics-software-for-coarse-grained-polymers) (not closed and decently upvoted) is an example of what I am saying.

Comment: @valerio to realize that that question you linked was closed? By me and a mod? Then the meta effect happened (post that crap question A was closed and it'll get reopened because some people are weak willed and don't care about site policies). Read the meta post I linked: they're off-topic and should remain as such. Such questions could be asked at [scicomp.se] or [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @KyleKanos I realize that it was reopened: that is allowed by the site. Also, from tpg2114's answer in the meta post you linked: "We can advise on numerical methods when tied to a physical problem and not a generic P/ODE (I am studying shock-turbulence interaction, is WENO or AUSM better? or What methods would one use to solve diffusion problems?)"

Answer (score 1):

[HOOMD-blue](http://glotzerlab.engin.umich.edu/hoomd-blue/) is another excellent choice. It can leverage high-performance parallel Monte Carlo simulations to look at the collective behaviour of particles with very complex shapes. [Here](http://hoomd-blue.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-hpmc.html) is the documentation for the Monte Carlo package, and [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.04692) is the paper that describes its usage and implementation.

Note that HOOMD-blue exposes python bindings, meaning that it can be run from a python script, which makes it very easy to manipulate the particles' degrees of freedom for the subsequent analysis.

Answer (score 0):

LAMMPS is a good option, as suggested by lemon.

The [region](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/region.html) command can be combined with the [create_atoms](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/create_atoms.html) command in order to fill a region of space of defined shape with atoms, with the crystal arrangement that you prefer. You have to

The region command allows you to define the following shapes:

- cube
- cone
- cylinder
- prism
- sphere
- plane

Plus the union/intersection of different shapes.