# Is there a "standard" quantum simulator/animator for pedagogy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, simulations, education, software

I'm having a hard time finding animations for 1D or 2D square well, SHO, free particle with barriers, etc, that I'm sure are "trustworthy". It's the sort of thing I would do in python in my spare time if I had any, and I know plenty of people have done it, but I don't like trusting someone's random github repo or youtube channel. Is there a recommended Youtube channel or PC/Mac program that is maintained, trustworthy, and somewhat user-friendly? I'm aware of some of the pedagogy outfits like QuiLT and Phet that make flash programs for teaching, but I find those a bit clunky/old/low-level; I'm looking basically for a more general Schrodinger equation solver for a user-specified potential, or just a repository of animations.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10311/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Any luck?......

Comment: No luck -- I ended up using "someone's random github repo", a python module called "schrod" (https://github.com/dhudsmith/schrod). While not exactly what I was looking for, I did successfully use it to make various plots and animations for my class.

Comment: https://github.com/Paul-G2/TDSE I like this one. Solves the time-dependent Schrodinger equation. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoCLRhXLs5MFSN7FMb-VlCA is his youtube channel