# How do I simulate an atom?

Tags: wavefunction, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, simulations

Let us assume I wish to simulate a Helium atom, since there does not exist a closed-form solution.

However, I presume I would need to simulate the time-dependent Schrodinger wave equation. I would like to know what the time-dependent hamiltonian looks like for this.

I think I would need the terms for electromagnetic, strong, and weak nuclear forces --- I do not think I need relativistic corrections, since I'm only interested in local information.

I wish to simulate an equation on simulation gives me the evolving probability distributions of the electrons.

I understand that this might be computationally infeasible, but I still wish to know what the *exact PDE is* that I need to solve --- I'm not looking for approximations!

Comment: How much QM background have you got and why do you think you need to include any forces other than electromagnetic? That said, best of luck with it.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate the nucleus and the electrons or just find the energy levels of the atom?

Comment: I want to understand how feasible it is to simulate the nucleus for visualization purposes --- hence I want the actual probability distributions .

Comment: ah that'll be a complicated hamiltonian then

Comment: Indeed; I wanted to know what it looks like :)

Comment: Related as regards background reading, but not quite your question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10311/does-there-exist-a-free-good-molecule-atom-simulation-software.  I would recommend you read the comment about the speed of resulting simulations, even without nuclear simulations.

Comment: @StudyStudy: I know relatively little (upto high-school/one-intro-course-in-undergrad level) quantum mechanics. I know a lot more quantum computing, so I do understand the quantum mechanics formalism (state spaces, time evolution, etc).

Comment: In addition to the two electrons, you want to simulate what is going on in the nucleus but not what is going on in the protons and neutrons?

Comment: Insofar as it affects the electrons, yes. I mostly care about the electron distributions. I have heard(?) that there are processes in the nucleus that might affect the electron density.

Comment: *evolving probability distributions of the electrons* The probability distribution in an energy eigenstate doesn’t evolve.

Comment: Nobody does it like this, because the tiny nuclear effects are probably smaller than the numerical errors in solving for the electrons.

Comment: Brute force simulation of processes at widely different scales is usually not a productive approach to understanding physical systems.

Comment: I was under the impression that the equation is time-dependent, and hence the eigenstates _could_ evolve. Can you please clarify what I'm missing? :) Also, is it really true that the only things that matter are the classical forces? That's very surprising to me; I thought _a lot_ of modern chemistry explanations relied on subtle interactions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103631/discussion-between-siddharth-bhat-and-g-smith).

Comment: *For what purpose* do you wish to simulate the hydrogen atom?  Simulation is a form of modelling.  Modelling works by designing *a tractable simplification* of the thing being modelled.  Simplifications work by ignoring/removing unimportant aspects/features and focusing only on those features that are important for the model's purpose.  For that reason the first question you should always ask when modelling something is "*what is the purpose of this model?*"  That will then serve as your guide in determining *how* to model it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [Hamiltonian for the He atom is](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al.)/09%3A_The_Electronic_States_of_the_Multielectron_Atoms/9.01%3A_The_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation_For_Multi-Electron_Atoms):
$$H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m_e}(\nabla_1^2 + \nabla_2^2) - \frac{2e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r_1}
 - \frac{2e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r_2}
 + \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r_{12}}$$
where the electrons are denoted 1 and 2, and $r_i$ is the distance to the nucleus at the origin and $r_{12}$ the distance between the electrons. Since the electrons have 3D position vectors $\mathbf{r_i}$ this corresponds to 6 degrees of freedom.

[One can reformulate the equation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/286a/4a4a6dc752acfa693a6555eb112489514220.pdf) to only act in $r_1,r_2,r_{12}$ coordinates for the spherically symmetric $^1S$ state. [With the right approximation methods](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5124/cd63876e9d2e173a758ba450e39b64f8be43.pdf) one can get energy eigenvalues with absurd precision. But I suspect the aim of the question is rather to let loose an electrong wave packet and see how it sloshes around.

Simulating the nucleus requires quite a lot more elaboration. Now you have 4 particles, making a 12D state space (18 in total). The hamiltonian is about the same but with more interaction terms (see [section 3.1](https://www.kth.se/social/files/58d26e56f27654419542e9c8/Lecture2014.pdf)), corresponding to nucleon-nucleon potentials that [generally look somewhat messy](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nucl-th/0702078.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer! This was exactly what I was looking for. So I can add the nuclear terms to the Hamiltonian and let it loose, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat This equation is already 6-dimensional. Have you ever solved a PDE with 6 or more dimensions on a computer? How many lattice points did you use in each dimension?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat How many points per dimension could you fit in your computer for an 18-dimensional computation? Not even 4!

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that this Hamiltonian ignores the fact that each electron, because it has spin, also has a (small) magnetic interaction with the proton and with the other electron.

Comment: @G.Smith the OP wanted to avoid relativistic corrections, and magnetic term definitely has a $c^{-1}$ factor. Otherwise you'd need to also include all the other relativistic corrections.

Comment: @Ruslan Yes, but the OP’s requests were rather inconsistent regarding what to include, as these magnetic effects are much larger than any effects due to, say, the weak nuclear force. And the OP said “I'm not looking for approximations” without understanding that they are unavoidable (as far as I know). Finally, the OP seems to have incorrectly thought that relativistic effects are nonlocal.